# Postgres JDBC maven dependency not found

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I wanted to include Postgres JDBC driver in my Java application, so I added it as maven dependency. I chose the last version from [this list](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/postgresql/postgresql), which happened to be, to my astonishment, hosted by Atlassian.
Now I am receiving this error:

> Missing artifact postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.4.1208-jdbc42-atlassian-hosted

I also tried an older version that is not hosted by Atlassian, but got the same error!
Is there another proper place to get the jar from?

This is my current pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>PostgresListener</groupId>
<artifactId>PostgresListener</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/postgresql/postgresql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.1208-jdbc42-atlassian-hosted</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Try this one: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.postgresql%22%20AND%20a%3A%22postgresql%22

Comment: Could you please post your pom or dependency?

Comment: Why are you trying to use a third-party dependency, instead of the official postgresql JDBC maven dependency?

Comment: Where is the official one, I found this on the mvnrepository.com, that is a part of my question: is there a better repository/host.

Comment: mvnrepository.com is just a view (index) of repo1.maven.org (and some other non-standard repository, like that one from Atlassian), but to answer your question: it is here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What exactly do you have in your `pom.xml` file?

Should be something like:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.1212</version>
</dependency>
```

Make sure you're using `org.postgresql` as the `groupId`, instead of `postgresql`.

Comment: This one worked, but how did you find it? A google search wont get me to it!

Comment: @AHH https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html, links to Maven using the link http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.postgresql%22%20AND%20a%3A%22postgresql%22

Answer (score 3):

Should be:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Do not put the version. Let Maven does that itself

Answer (score 0):

If you use DBeaver, try this:

1. Choose Database option from menu,
2. Driver manager,
3. choose PostgreSQL and edit this,
4. Go to Libraries and choose **Add Artifact**,
5. Dependency Declaration,
6. Paste your needed dependency (in the above answers) into it, and you're done

Answer (score -2):

Just downgrade the version of postgresql